# How to parse out the first name, lastname and middle name out of this fullname

Tags: t-sql, select, sql-server-2012

How to parse out the first name, lastname and middle name out of this fullname

Example

```
 Fullname 
 ------------------
 Jose,KENNETH;N
```

Comment: Suggested reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your name always contain three parts, and none of them is longer than 128 chars, and none of them contains a dot, you can (ab)use `parsename`:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 'Jose,KENNETH;N'

SELECT  PARSENAME(fullName, 1) As MiddleName,
        PARSENAME(fullName, 2) As FirstName,
        PARSENAME(fullName, 3) As LastName
FROM (VALUES(REPLACE(REPLACE(@string, ';', '.'), ',', '.'))) V(fullName)
```

Results:

```
MiddleName  FirstName   LastName
N           KENNETH     Jose
```

Answer (score 0):

`APPLY` is your friend.

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 'Jose,KENNETH;N'

SELECT 
  FullName  = @string,
  FirstName = SUBSTRING(@string,0,a.pos),
  LastName  = SUBSTRING(@string,a.pos+1,b.pos-a.pos-1),
  Middle    = SUBSTRING(@string,b.pos+1,8000)
FROM        (VALUES(CHARINDEX(',',@string)))       AS a(pos)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(';',@string,a.pos))) AS b(pos);
```

**Results:**

```
FullName           FirstName  LastName  Middle
------------------ ---------- --------- --------
Jose,KENNETH;N     Jose       KENNETH   N
```

**UPDATED PER THE OP's COMMENTS**

**Without using `APPLY`:**

```
SELECT 
  FullName  = @string,
  FirstName = SUBSTRING(@string,0,CHARINDEX(',',@string)),
  LastName  = SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX(',',@string)+1,CHARINDEX(';',@string,CHARINDEX(',',@string))-CHARINDEX(',',@string)-1),
  Middle    = SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX(';',@string,CHARINDEX(',',@string))+1,8000);
```

Comment: Note that I'm operating under the assumption that Jose is the first name. If not then the fix should be easy. ;)

Comment: Thank Alan! Jose is the lastname. is there anyway to parse this without using cross apply. instead something like this SUBSTRING(replace(name,';',''), 1, CHARINDEX(',', replace(name,';','')) - 1)

Comment: You could do that without cross apply but that would make a longer, more cumbersome code.

Comment: @jason312 I updated my answer. As Zohar eluded to, APPLY allows for cleaner code. Note how, using APPLY I can create this expression:  `CHARINDEX(',',@string)` then reference the expression 4X times as `a.pos`. This, with no performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you !!!

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 'Jose,KENNETH;N'       
select @string AS FullName, substring(@string,1,CHARINDEX(',',@string)-1) as LastName,
SUBSTRING(@string,charindex(',',@string)+1,len(@string)-Charindex(',',@string)-charindex(';',REVERSE(@string))) as FirstName,
SUBSTRING(@string,Charindex(';',@string)+1,len(@string)) as MiddleName
```